# Autohotkey Bug? Variable being emptied in unrelated function

Tags: function, autohotkey

TLDR: Why is this code (within a larger script), showing floors=0 (what its supposed to be) on the first msgbox, and no value on the 2nd msgbox? (this only happens within the larger script. If i supply the same inputs and outputs to a small test script it works as expected)

I have a script I use as a control panel for functions I can run at my work.
Part of it is a function that saves the last opened path for the 'design'.
An unrelated part of the 3k line script has a floor variable that was randomly becoming empty. I tracked down that it happened whenever I run this 'exitfunc'.
What is crazy is that it happens every time i call the exitfunc in multiple different parts of my script, but when i create a script with just the information that is sent to the script and the ini it writes to, the variable isnt deleted. This has to be a bug, but I am not sure what to do about it. Oh and even though its called ExitFunc, Im just too lazy to rename it. It activates many times throughout the script.

```
msgbox % Floors
ExitFunc(UserData,Path2)
msgbox % Floors

ExitFunc(UserData,Path2){
IniWrite, %Path2%,%USERDATA%\DesignSRecent.ini,NewDesignSLast,LastPath2
ExitCode=0
SaveCheckListFunc(UserData)
loop, 15
{
    IniRead, PathXT,%USERDATA%\DesignSRecent.ini,NewDesignS,%A_Index%
    PathX := StrSplit(PATHXT,"[.]").2
    If (Path2=PathX)
    {
        ExitCode=1
        FormatTime,CurrentTime,,yyyyMMddHHmmss
        Var:=CurrentTime "[.]" Path2
        IniWrite, %Var%,%USERDATA%\DesignSRecent.ini,NewDesignS,%A_Index%
    }
}
If Path2=NOT FOUND
    ExitCode=1
if ExitCode=0
{
    PathWriteNum=0
    loop, 15
    {
        IniRead, PathXT,%USERDATA%\DesignSRecent.ini,NewDesignS,%A_Index%
        If PathXT=Error
            PathWriteNum:=A_Index
    }
    If PathWriteNum=0
    {
        PATHXFULL := SortPathsFunc(UserDATA)
        PATHXARRAY := StrSplit(PathXFULL,",")
        PATHXTAOLDEST := PATHXARRAY[PATHXARRAY.Count()]
        PathWriteNum := StrSplit(PATHXTAOLDEST,"[.]").3
    }
    FormatTime,CurrentTime,,yyyyMMddHHmmss
    Var:=CurrentTime "[.]" Path2
    IniWrite, %Var%,%USERDATA%\DesignSRecent.ini,NewDesignS,%PathWriteNum%
}
}
```

Comment: Note I get it might be hard/impossible to figure out the cause without seeing the rest of the script. But its too long and has sensitive information. And isnt commented. or neat.

Comment: You also have to look at the other functions called, e.g. `SaveCheckListFunc(UserData)` and `SortPathsFunc(UserDATA)` Also you can troubleshoot by echoing `msgbox % Floors` inside different parts of the function to narrow down where it could be cleared